# In C#, if any asynchronous operation in a method makes an entire method async, why would I need more than one await statement in the method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Why doesn't one await statement make all other statements in the same method async-await calls?

[From MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/):

```
static async Task<Toast> MakeToastWithButterAndJamAsync(int number)
{
    var toast = await ToastBreadAsync(number);
    ApplyButter(toast);
    ApplyJam(toast);

    return toast;
}
```

On the page it says,

> Composition with tasks
>
> You have everything ready for breakfast at the same time except the
> toast. Making the toast is the composition of an asynchronous
> operation (toasting the bread), and synchronous operations (adding the
> butter and the jam). Updating this code illustrates an important
> concept:
>
> Important
>
> The composition of an asynchronous operation followed by synchronous
> work is an asynchronous operation. Stated another way, if any portion
> of an operation is asynchronous, the entire operation is asynchronous.

Later on in the [final version](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/snippets/index/AsyncBreakfast-final/Program.cs), one of the methods shows two await statements.  Why?  If the method has the first `await` on `Task.Delay`, why do I need another `await` on the second `Task.Delay`?  Wouldn't the `Task.Delay` make this async thread "await" here anyway?

```
private static async Task<Bacon> FryBaconAsync(int slices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"putting {slices} slices of bacon in the pan");
            Console.WriteLine("cooking first side of bacon...");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            for (int slice = 0; slice < slices; slice++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("flipping a slice of bacon");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("cooking the second side of bacon...");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Put bacon on plate");

            return new Bacon();
        }
```

This did not tell me the why:  [Why do we need more than one `await` statement in a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083531/why-do-we-need-more-than-one-await-statement-in-a-c-sharp-method)

Nor this,

[C# Async Await with Synchronous and Asynchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569277/c-sharp-async-await-with-synchronous-and-asynchronous-operation)

Comment: If you do not `await` something that is `async` then you are "firing and forgetting" meaning you are not waiting for the task to complete.  That means your method can complete before the Task you didn't await.  Awaiting one thing in a method does not automatically make it await everything else.

Comment: If I took out the second await here, what would happen then?

Comment: `this async thread` - there is [no such thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17661428/11683). I take it when you say "make async" you mean "start running this on a separate thread"; this is not what happens. `If I took out the second await here, what would happen then?` - then "Put bacon on plate" would appear immediately after "cooking the second side of bacon...", rather than three seconds later.

Comment: @GSerg yes, that is what I thought was happening.

Comment: @learntofix Click the link then. Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34680985/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37419572/11683 and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html.

Comment: *"Why do I need another `await` on the second `Task.Delay`?"* -- The first `await Task.Delay` represents the cooking of the bacon's first side. The second `await Task.Delay` represents the cooking of the bacon's second side. So your question, as I understand it, is *"why do we need to cook the bacon from both sides?"* Which is a peculiar question to ask. If you are satisfied with a half-baked bacon, nobody can argue against that. It's none of our business to tell you how to eat your bacon!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias lol, but my point is the delay would happen regardless, I thought, so why do I need the method to stop there?

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you think that the `Task.Delay(3000)` is equivalent with the `await Task.Delay(3000)`, and in both cases the method will be suspended at that point for 3 seconds? Or you believe that suspending the method is not needed, because baking the bacon's second side can happen instantaneously?

Comment: The reason "Why doesn't one await statement make all other statements in the same method async-await calls?" is because that's not how the C# designers designed this part of the language. If you want to know what went through their head when they decided on this, only they can answer that. I would imagine the main reason would be that you can then grab the tasks you want to let finish in parallel and await them after spawning all of them, the choice is then yours.

Comment: I think I simply don't understand the definition.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias when in that async method when it hits await, is that method "stopped" until that await is done?  Nothing else runs until that await is done in that method (synchronous)?

Comment: Yes, the `await` suspends the asynchronous method, until the awaitable completes. Other things might be happening concurrently elsewhere, but the method (or using another term "the execution flow") is suspended.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Delay` doesn't delay your *current* task. It creates *another* task that waits for that amount. So if you just do `Task.Delay(123)` you are spawning *another* task that waits for 123 ms, but your *current* task doesn't wait for that *spawned* task to finish. In order to make your *current* task wait for 123 ms as well, you need to `await Task.Delay(123)`, which makes the *current* task wait for the *spawned* task, which waits for 123 ms. Because `await` pauses the *current* task's execution at that point to wait for the given *other* task to complete.

---

**Note:** Please note the [comment by Theodor Zoulias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127149/in-c-if-any-asynchronous-operation-in-a-method-makes-an-entire-method-async-w#comment129154876_73127687):

> It's better to say that the Task.Delay creates a task that will **complete after** that amount of time. There is **no waiting** taking place internally.

Comment: *"It creates another task that waits for that amount."* -- I am afraid that using the term "waits" to explain the `Task.Delay` method, can result in confusion. IMHO it's better to say that the `Task.Delay` creates a task that will *complete after* that amount of time. There is no waiting taking place internally. If you create 1,000,000 `Task.Delay` tasks, you are not creating 1,000,000 [waiters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter).

Answer (score 1):

`await`s are there so that the next statement executes after the work is done.

Let's imagine a piece of code that requires a sequence of steps.

```
async Task<bool> ProcessAsync() 
{
   var data = await GetDataAsync();
   await SendDataOrThrowAsync(data);
   return true; // Success
}
```

The 1st await is easy - you cannot send data before you get it.
The 2nd await is there so that `return true` is executed only when the sending is finished.

Without the 2nd await the contract changes.

```
async Task<bool> ProcessAsync() 
{
   var data = await GetDataAsync();
   SendDataOrThrowAsync(toast); // don't wait just start
   return true; // Success
}
```

A `true` here means that we started sending not that we sent it.

---

I think this is also a good example that I hope helps clearing the confusion.

With

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
await Task.Delay(2000);

DoWork();
```

`DoWork` will be called after 3 seconds.

With

```
await Task.Delay(1000); // Start, and pause execution here until done
Task.Delay(2000); // Start, but don't pause;

DoWork();
```

`DoWork` will be called after 1 second.

Having the ability to to `await` or not to `await` allows you to do multiple things at the same time.

```
async Task<int> GetFirstHalfAsync() => await Task.Delay(1000);
async Task<int> GetSecondHalfAsync() => await Task.Delay(3000);

(...)

var t1 = GetFirstHalfAsync(); // Start, don't pause here
var t2 = GetFirstHalfAsync(); // Start, don't pause here

var results = await Task.WhenAll(new Task<int>[] { t1, t2 }); // Pause here until we get the results
```